# Set BLE connection parameters

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I would like to decrease the power consumption of the BLE device. When I connect BLE device to PC, then the power consumption drops, because the PC application accepts the suggested connection parameters (suggested by the BLE device). When I connect the same device to the Android phone the power consumption is quite high.

When I was playing around with the connection parameters I saw that the power consumption is directly related with the BLE connection settings.

Because of that I would like to know how I can change the BLE connection setting in my Android application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#requestConnectionPriority(int) and choose between three different settings. If you want another setting you will have to initiate the connection parameters update from the slave side.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Not working. I also edited connection settings from the slave and they are not used.

Comment: What do you mean with "not working"? Both suggestions surely works... Have you looked at the hci snoop log or a sniffer trace?